# Flask jsonify print results on new lines

Tags: python, html, json, flask

First time using Flask, I have created a very basic app and I am trying to print the results of a recommender system. The first set of code is from my python function (print_most_similar) and is creating a formatted string in hopes to print every REC on a new line. The second section of code is obviously my flask routing. You can see that the flask part calls the function, so it is returned 'y'. 
I believe the jsonify will not take the \n characters.
I have tried using just '\n' in the string formatting, but it just appears as a string. As does '\t'.

```
for k in range(len(sugg)):
    x = str("REC {}: {}\\n".format(k+1, sugg[k]))
    y += x
return y

@app.route("/getrecomm",methods=['GET','POST'])
def getrecomm():
    restname = request.args.get('restname', type=str)
    number = request.args.get('number', type=int)
    i = getBusIndex(restname, names)
return make_response(jsonify(result=(print_most_similar(rating, names, i, number))),200)
```

Currently, the results print like this:
REC 1: Harbor House Cafe & Lounge\nREC 2: Starbucks\nREC 3: McDonald's\nREC 4: Taco Bell\nREC 5: Panda Express\n

I would like them to print like this:
REC 1: Harbor House Cafe & Lounge
REC 2: Starbucks
REC 3: McDonald's
REC 4: Taco Bell
REC 5: Panda Express

I'm using python 3, fyi. Any suggestions would be super appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried logging the jsonified content? Are `\n` characters included there (before they are returned)

Answer (score 2):

Summary

- **Answer**: `<br>`
- **Alternative**: JSONView Chrome Extension

The only one that give me good results was `<br>`:

Example

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        '<br>id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        '<br>id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In your browser the `<br>` character will be rendered as html and reproduce a new line.

Result:

 ["creates" new lines in json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AljSN.png)

Jsonify can't help you because it takes the values (integer,boolean,float, etc) as a string and avoid special characters like `\n`, `\t`, etc

Finally, if you just want a fancy way to visualize json files in your browser, you could use JSONView, is a Chrome extension that render Json files in a more understandable way, like this.

[rendering with JSONView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOSAS.png)

Comment: Doesnt work for me: still watch <br> in browser :(

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam can u share ur script/code?

Comment: `some_var = "some random text<br>"
res = f"Connected successfully to Postgres Server:<br> {some_var}<br>"
res += res "Connection closed"
return jsonify(res)`
still see <br> without new lines in browser

Comment: Yup, I get <br>'s too.

Comment: I created a very small file "401.html" and passed the string to it in python like this ```return render_template('401.html', message_data=html_string), 401```. Inside the 401.html file I had ```{{message_data | safe }}```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solutions.

It seems like that `jsonify()` function doesn't apply the "new lines" situation.

You can use `Response()`

```
from flask import Flask, Response

statement = """
        try
        try
        try
        """
@app.route('/**/api/v1/**', methods=['GET'])
def get_statement():
    return Response(statement, mimetype='text/plain')
```

I'm also new learner for flask, `Response()`function works on my app.