# Python+Flask : how to get text from request with newlines?

Tags: python, http, flask

I am not sure how it works, but it worked in one of my projects and doesn't works in a new one.
Obviously, I am missing something.

I want a simple REST server with only one POST.
It should get text from POST request. Text contains newlines.

This is my text.txt:

```
hello
how are you
```

This is how I test it:

```
curl -i -s -X POST -d @test.txt http://*ip*:*port*/api/gogogo
```

This is part of my python script with flask app:

```
@app.route('/gogogo', methods=['POST'])
def translate():
    request_str = request.get_data().decode('utf-8').strip()
    request_lines = request_str.split('\n')
    print(request_lines)
    return "yeah"
```

But "print(request_lines)" prints "hellohow are you".
Any ideas?
I also tried to use 
 instead of '\n', didn't help. And even if it did - my requests use '\n', so i have to support this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `curl`. It removes new line when you send it with `-d`.
You have to use `--data-binary`

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @test.txt http://localhost:5000/gogogo
```

---

**BTW:** you can test requests also with page https://httpbin.org which sends back as JSON all data which it get in request from you - headers, body, post data, url arguments.

It will also send back string without `\n` if you use `-d` instead of `--data-binary`

```
curl -X POST -d @test.txt https://httpbin.org/post

curl -X POST --data-binary @test.txt https://httpbin.org/post
```

---

**BTW:** Now it may send it with `\r\n` instead of `\n` but maybe it depend on system and how it keep new line in file. Better use `.splitlines()` instead of `.split('\n')`

Comment: oh god, it was unexpected. Thanks, really

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
request_str = request.get_data().decode('utf-8').strip()
request_lines = request_str.splitlines(True)
for line in request_lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: im quite new in python , trying my best to help...hahaha

Comment: Same. It prints one line "hellohow are you"

Comment: I think, it.is about Flask, not python. Request.get_data() returns one string without '\n'.

Comment: i see...ok i'll try look at flask

Comment: try "<br>" instead of  "\n" based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44349546/flask-jsonify-print-results-on-new-lines